# Where can I find data on the following variables?

Tags: data-request

I'm looking for data (US) on the following variables for the years 2000-2014:

[image]

Does anybody know where I can find such a data set or custom data table? Preferably all in one table (or a table per variable, including all states and all years).

Comment: have you tried anything? like search census.gov?

Comment: american factfinder

Comment: For those who can't see images hosted by imgur, what variables are you seeking?

Answer (score 0):

The Social Security Administration Decennial survey has such information. https://www.census.gov/prod/www/decennial.html. That said it’s stuck in pdf files by state and was last done in 2010.

For more recent estimates, the census population estimates has sex and race information by county for each state. https://www.census.gov/data/datasets/2016/demo/popest/counties-detail.html#ds